How to setup SSL certification for host inside CGNAT accessed via ddns
I am just learning networking (absolute noob, still) and NAS managing. I have a media server running an interface app with no security measures so far, and want to implement SSL certification through nginx reverse proxy as an exercise. So, here are the facts (with fictitious data, of course):

I have a media server running at local 192.162.0.44:10000 (port 10000 is forwarded to the address above in my router).

I am behind CGNAT, so to be able to access my server from the outside, my ISP forwarded ddns.ISPdomain.com:10000 to my router (don't know exactly what or how common this is, but they did me this favor so I didn't have to pay for a public IP).

I am able to access my server just fine from outside, browsing for ddns.ISPdomain.com:10000.


Now, I have acquired a domain mydomain.com and would like to SSL secure my server through reverse proxy. Does this make sense at all since the ip that I use to access my server from the outside is not even mine? How would I configure the nginx server? Should I host it on 192.162.0.44:10000 (since this is the port my ISP is pointing their forward to) and proxy to some other port to which I change my media server? Or should I get some means of hosting nginx in a public IP (I suppose I can do this with a free oracle VM), point mydomain.com to this new public IP and reverse proxy to ddns.ISPdomain.com:10000? And what about the ports? Supposing I cannot ask my ISP to forward any other port or change the port they already forwarded to me across CGNAT, how would https work since I'm not listening on 80 and 443? Can nginx listen for ssl secured connections on other ports?
I know that in my setup the best would be to use something like cloudfare or rathole tunnel, but in any case I would like to learn why the ssl is not appropriate in my case and all that is happening.
I apologize if all of this is written in the most confuse and imprecise way, but I appreciate any insights. My goal is only to learn this stuff.

As for SSL - all what matters is that the domain in the certificate matches the domain in the URL. The rest of your question has nothing to do with SSL and thus not with the title of your question, it is just about getting plain TCP connectivity from outside through the CGNAT and your router. If this is possible and how this is achieved depends on a) the ISP and b) the port forwarding configuration of your router. And yes, nginx can listen on any port for HTTP or HTTPS, as a simple research would have shown.

@SteffenUllrich Thank you for your answer. The way I can get external TCP connectivity is through a single port in my router to which my ISP have forwarded a DDNS of theirs. Furthermore, I understand that 443 is just the port a URL request with the HTTPS declared protocol defaults to, and have seen that I can set nginx to listen on different ports meaning just that the client would have to specify said ports upon request. However, I have received many contradictory answers to this on different forums, and am very confused.

"Supposing I cannot ask my ISP to forward any other port or change the port they already forwarded to me across CGNAT, how would https work since I'm not listening on 80 and 443?" - There is no requirement for HTTP or HTTPS to run on port 80 and 443 respectfully.  The correct port will be determined by the DNS and Apache or equivalent service.

If you managed to route the domain via CGNAT and router to the nginx inside your local network you just listen on 0.0.0.0:10000 (assuming you've forwarded to this port). You cannot listen on any address which is outside the machine running nginx, i.e. not on the address assigned to your router etc. Note that the URL then must use the externally visible port too unless it is 443 (i.e. default https), i.e. there is no other setting which lets the browser pick a different port just for a specific domain.

Also note that you cannot run HTTP and HTTPS on the same port, i.e. nginx does not support this. So if you want both protocols you need to get two ports from the ISP and forward both to nginx and listen on both in nginx.

@SteffenUllrich I understand that I need to listen on nginx on the LAN ip to which my one 'external' router port is forwarded and that since I have that one port, I cannot listen on both http and https (and redirect the former to the latter, as is usually done). My question basically is: if I host nginx on the LAN:10000 (which 'receives' from ddns...:10000 which receives from mydomain.com), proxy pass connections to LAN:X where now I host my application, and configure server_name on nginx to mydomain.com, with a letsencrypt cert, will it work as I expect? I.e., will connections be encrypted?

@GaloisFan: yes, this should do it.

if your domain registrar allows for it, letsencrypt/certbot can verify the domain using DNS validation and issue the cert.
